# Store Oauth state in a DB or AES-256 Cookie

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, authorization, twitter-oauth

I am using Oauth 1.0a (Twitter specifically).  The Oauth flow for authorization contains state, specifically, the client (my App) must maintain the "Request Token Secret" until the user (in the browser) Authenticates with Twitter and then returns with the Oauth_Verifier.

Problem:  I use DNS load balancing across several web servers with a low TTL (1 minute) for fail-over, so I want my app servers to be stateless.

I have two solutions in mind:

1)  Store the request_token_secret in an encrypted cookie (AES-256) and let the user's browser resend it to whichever server the DNS points to at the time

2)  Store the Request_token_secret in a database with the ID of the request_token

I prefer the first because its faster and cheaper, but I am not sure if it creates a security issue.  Any issues with option #1?

Comment: Are you using HTTPS? Otherwise someone could sniff that cookie. They cannot decrypt it, but they could send it back to your server and maybe pass themselves off as the user that way.

Comment: Yes, I am using HTTPS

Comment: In fact, I will use HTTPS with the cookie having the 'Secure Only' flag and the 'HTTP Only' flag and it will be a session cookie.